# How to switch on/off the "spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy","LEGACY"?

Tags: time, reset, legacy

Hi I was asked to program a function which can switch between time legacy and back.

```
"spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy","LEGACY"
```

It should be possible to set the time legacy on and do datetime conversions.
It should als be possible to reset the option.

How can this be done?

So far I could find only information about how to set the option

```
 spark.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy","LEGACY")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use spark.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy","CORRECTED") to reset the option.

Here is the link for your reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/language-manual/parameters/legacy_time_parser_policy